# Why a parameter value is not being passed from C# code to stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, blazor-server-side

I have a C# Blazor app which calls a service and the service in turn calls a stored procedure. When the app calls the service a csv string is passed to the service and this service should pass the parameter value to the stored procedure.

However that doesn't seem to be happening. When I debug C# code the CSV string is successfully created and that string does successfully get passed to the service. The stored procedure itself does work when executed in SSMS. It just seems the step of the service passing the csv string to the stored procedure doesn't seem to be working.

App code calling the service:

```
public async Task SelectProcesses()
{
    var SelectedData = await PRDSRVGrid.GetSelectedRecords();

    foreach (var a in SelectedData) 
    {
         IDValue.Add(a.PRODSERVID); 
    }

    string csvstring = (string.Join(",", IDValue.Select(x => x.ToString())));
    SelectedProductsServices = csvstring;

    processes = await SelectSpecificProcessesService.GetSpecificProcesses(@SelectedProductsServices);
    return;
}
```

The service itself:

```
using Dapper;
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ThePositionerBlazorServerDapperSyncfusion.Data
{
    public class SelectSpecificProcessesService : ISelectSpecificProcessesService
    {
        private readonly SqlConnectionConfiguration _configuration;

        public SelectSpecificProcessesService(SqlConnectionConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _configuration = configuration;
        }

        public async Task<IEnumerable<PROCESSES>> GetSpecificProcesses(string @SelectedProductsServices)
        {
            IEnumerable<PROCESSES> processes;

            using (var conn = new SqlConnection(_configuration.Value))
            {
                var parameters = new DynamicParameters();
                parameters.Add("(@SelectedProductsServices", SelectedProductsServices, DbType.String);

                //await conn.ExecuteAsync("SelectSpecificProcesses", parameters, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);

                processes = await conn.QueryAsync<PROCESSES>("SelectSpecificProcesses", parameters, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
            }

            return processes;
        }
    }
}
```

And the stored procedure:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SelectSpecificProcesses]
    @SelectedProductsServices nvarchar(4000)
AS
    SELECT PROCESSID, PROCESSDESC, LASTUPDATED
    FROM PROCESSES
    WHERE PROCESSID IN (
        SELECT PROCESSID
        FROM WORKHIER W
        JOIN iter_charlist_to_tbl(@SelectedProductsServices, DEFAULT) s
            ON w.PRODSERVID = s.nstr
    )

    RETURN
```

It complains about the `@SelectedProductsServices` not being provided - a SQL Server error.

Any advice would be helpful. Thanking you in advance ...

Comment: `parameters.Add("(` doesn't look right to me.

Comment: Why don't you use a table valued parameter instead of some horrible string-splitting?

Comment: 1) Please provide the exact error message. 2) Best guess you are passing a C# null instead of DBNull.Value.

Comment: turns out that Stu caught the issue- it was the extra bracket in parameter.add statement- thanks!

Answer (score 0):

it was stu's answer

turns out that Stu caught the issue- it was the extra bracket in parameter.add statement- thanks!